# How to specify Cloud Run endpoint for PubSub Subscription in Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I am building docker which involves cloud run deployment and want to add a PubSub push subscription in next step with Cloud Run as an endpoint. How can I link the endpoint url that I get in previous step?

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--network=cloudbuild', '-t', 'gcr.io/project-${_ENVIRONMENT}/cloud_run-pubsub_example', './cloud-run/file_upserter/']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several solutions for this.

- First, the url of the Cloud Run managed is still the same: --.run.app

  - Service name is known
  - Project hash never change. Deploy once to get it
  - Zone never changes. Deploy once to get it
- If you want to cover the first deployment, write a script file

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions create <push Subscription name> --topic <topic name> \
    --push-endpoint=$(gcloud beta run services describe <service Name> --region <region> \
    --format "value(status.address.hostname)" \
    --platform managed)
```

In Cloud Build, add this step

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['<scriptFilePath>']
```

Comment: It works, just needed --platform as well. Thank you.